# Ballerina - can we check response status code for a URL like www.google.com?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-http

I am new to Ballerina, and i want to know if I can find the response status of any url.
This is basically to check if the system is up or down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of the Ballerina http client sample to demonstrate how to obtain the response status code.

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    http:Client clientEP = new ("http://www.mocky.io");
    var resp = clientEP->get("/v2/5ae082123200006b00510c3d/");
    if (resp is http:Response) {
        var payload = resp.getTextPayload();
        io:println(resp.statusCode); // print http status code
        if (payload is string) {
            io:println(payload);
        } else {
            io:println(payload.detail());
        }
    } else {
        io:println(resp.detail());
    }
}
```

This sample was taken from [here](https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/by-example/hello-world-client.html).